# How to remove useless whitespaces from className in React with eslint/prettier?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, eslint, prettier

I faced a problem. I noticed that in React projects prettier doesn't fix such problem as useless whitespaces in classNames. For example:

```html
<img
    className='hidden  lg:block '
    src='./images/image-product-desktop.jpg'
    alt='product'
/>
```

I found *prettier-plugin-tailwindcss*, but it doesn't remove these whitespaces. And I tried to change tailwind include languages, but it didn't work too. How do I fix this?

This is part of my **settings.json**:

```json
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
},
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "typescript": "typescript",
    "javascript": "javascript",
    "html": "HTML",
    "javascriptreact": "javascriptreact",
    "typescriptreact": "typescriptreact"
},
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

My **prettier** settings:

```json
{
    "semi": false,
    "useTabs": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "printWidth": 120,
    "singleAttributePerLine": true,
    "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"]
}
```

And my **eslint** config:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "plugin:tailwindcss/recommended"
    ],
    "overrides": [],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "react-hooks", "tailwindcss", "prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "react/function-component-definition": [
            2,
            {
                "namedComponents": "function-declaration",
                "unnamedComponents": "arrow-function"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

I found out that plugin developers tried to fix that [issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/pull/70), but it was [reverted](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/pull/72).

Is there any way to fix this? I appreciate any help.

Comment: _I found out that developers fixed that issue_ -- It was reverted: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/pull/72